# Excluding folders on CheckMarx scan

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, checkmarx, sast, devsecops

I'm working on implementing Checkmarx scans in our code repository. I'm using Jenkins and the CheckMarx plugin to accomplish this task.  There are some folders I want to exclude from the scan; referencing the Jenkins [plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/checkmarx/#stepclass-cxscanbuilder-execute-checkmarx-scan) documentation it seems like all I have to do is add the folder names in the 'excludeFolders' field.  However that doesn't appear to work, or maybe I don't have the value entered correctly.

I've tried '/test', 'test/', '!**/test/**/*' but none work and the folder is still registered and zipped before it is uploaded to our CheckMarx server.

Below is what I have in my pipeline:

```
stage("Running CheckMarks for Layer"){
            steps{
                script{
                    def layer_dir = readFile file: 'layer-list'
                    def layer_list = layer_dir.split('\\r?\\n')
                    println (layer_list)
                    layer_list.each { layer ->
                        print (layer)
                        dir("${env.WORKSPACE}/layers/layer-name/$layer"){
                            step([
                                $class: 'CxScanBuilder',
                                comment: 'Layer scanning',
                                credentialsId: 'XXXX',
                                excludeFolders: 'test',
                                exclusionsSetting: 'global',
                                failBuildOnNewResults: false,
                                failBuildOnNewSeverity: 'MEDIUM',
                                filterPattern: '''!**/_cvs/**/*, !Checkmarx/Reports/*.*''',
                                fullScanCycle: 10,
                                incremental: true,
                                fullScansScheduled: true,
                                generatePdfReport: true,
                                preset: '36',
                                teamPath: "\\path\\to\\codebase",
                                projectName: "$layer",
                                sastEnabled: true,
                                sourceEncoding: '1',
                                vulnerabilityThresholdResult: 'FAILURE',
                                waitForResultsEnabled: true
                            ])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Any suggestions on how to exclude the 'test' folder?

Answer (score 3):

You should change your exclusionsSetting to **'job'** instead of **'global'**, we can't override the global configurations.

Then you can add more filters in the **filterPattern**.

Answer (score 1):

Modify like below to exclude both target and test folders.

**excludeFolders: 'target, test'**

*Jenkins console log:*

```
[Cx-Debug]: Excluded Dir: src/test
[Cx-Debug]: Excluded Dir: target
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on Windows you need to use the following pattern: !**\\test\\**\\*

On Linux: !**/test/**/*

Answer (score 0):

the filtering is really flakey - did you have any luck????

try add it to the filterPattern as `!Test/*.*` as well and play around with that...